# Error Signing Playbook App: Code signing request failed because this file has been previously signed

Tags: signing, blackberry-playbook

When I sign my playbook app I get the error:

```
    Connecting to url http://www.rim.net/Websigner/servlet/RDK-Waterloo
Sending properties to server...
Properties of response := [
Version = 1
Response = Signature Response
Confirm = null
Error = Code signing request failed because this file has been previously signed
.
]
barsigner error: server error: Code signing request failed because this file has
 been previously signed.
```

I understand that this error means I have to bump the version of my app. Where do I specify the version? I tried bumping the `<widget>` version, I even added a `<versionNumber>` tag. Nothing seems to work. Can someone look at my `config.xml` and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<widget xmlns=" http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:rim="http://www.blackberry.com/ns/widgets"
        version="3.0.2">

    <rim:navigation mode="focus" />
    <name>AppName</name>
    <description>My Description.</description>
    <author href="" rim:copyright="Copyright © 2011 TG.">TG</author>
    <versionNumber>3.0.2</versionNumber>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <icon src="assets/icon.png"/>
    <access uri="*" subdomains="true" />
    <license>
        Copyright © 2011 TG.
        THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND,
        EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF
        MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND
        NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS
        BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN
        ACTION OF CONTRACT, INSULT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN
        CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE
        SOFTWARE.
    </license>
</widget>
```

I am using the following commands for Signing:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Research In Motion\BlackBerry WebWorks Packager for PlayBook\bbwp\bbwp" "D:\work\App.zip" -gcsk pass -gp12 pass -buildId 1 -o "D:\work\bin"

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Research In Motion\BlackBerry WebWorks Packager for PlayBook\bbwp\blackberry-tablet-sdk\bin\blackberry-signer" -verbose -cskpass pass -keystore sigtool.p12 -storepass pass "D:\work\bin\App.bar" RDK
```

Comment: X posted on: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-Development/Error-Signing-Playbook-App-Code-signing-request-failed-because/td-p/1015211

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sign a WebWorks package only the following command is needed:

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Research In Motion\BlackBerry WebWorks Packager for PlayBook\bbwp\bbwp" "D:\work\App.zip" -gcsk pass -gp12 pass -buildId 1 -o "D:\work\bin"`

Obviously following it up with the second command was reporting that the app version was already signed since the first command registered the version!

Answer (score 1):

On your "blackberry-tablet.xml" change the field "buildId".